# Is all unitray matrix Haar distributed.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, functional-analysis

I have seen in the literature statement as "Haar distributed Unitary matrix". I have also seen that every unitary matrix has a invariant Haar measure. My question is why use the term "Haar distributed unitary matrix'? Is there a unitary matrix which is which is not Haar distributed? Would someone please help me to understand?

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, there is no matrix which is Haar distributed.

The expression/statement "$U $ is a Haar distributed unitary matrix" is abusive language for "$U $ is a (matrix valued) **random variable** which is Haar distributed".

Precisely, this means that for every Borel subset $M $ of the set of unitary matrices, we have
$$
\Bbb {P}(U \in M) =\mu (M ),
$$
where $\mu $ is the normalised Haar measure on the group of unitary matrices.

Of course, there are (unitary matrix valued) random variables which are not Haar distributed, for example every constant random variable (with constant value a unitary matrix) will do.

Comment: May i ask if P in the equation means probability?

Comment: @Creator: Yes, it does.